# Why is while loop much slower than for loop in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of these two loop method, I tried number from 0 to 99999 using `for in` and `while` loop clause.

```
for i in 0..<s.count - 9 {
  print("\(i)")
}

var j = 0
while j < s.count - 9 {
  print("\(j)")
  j = j+1
}
```

In both loop, will print the current number and add number by 1 until it reaches 99999.
Turns out that `for` in clause use **0.91** to go through every number, at same time `while` take much much much longer time (around **80.8**).

I searched on Internet and documents, but cannot figure out why.

What cause this huge performance difference?

Comment: `s.count` is only called once in the 1st code and it is called `s.count - 9` times in the 2nd code.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, yes. I got it. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Xin Note that you shouldn't do any performance test inside playground. If you want to test add it to a project and compile it using  release mode.